# Visual Composer

Tags: wordpress, carousel, visual-composer

Programming novice here.  I'm editing a WP site already constructed using visual composer, but having trouble creating responsive elements.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as there's little out there in the way of guides.

Problem:  I'm trying to use the default image carousel as a large header image(s).  I can get one to sit in a new row, but the images contained are sticking to their original dimensions (1200x700), with no responsive resizing.

The row is 'stretch row and content no padding), how can I make it's carousel content stretch 100% by width?  Ive tried with a single image with similar results :(

Any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Dezza - did you ever get a resolution on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a single image, you should just use a single image element instead of an image carousel. I tried this out and it image in a image element would resize according to the *viewport* size.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your row options and set the margin to 0px. For it to span all the way across you should set the margin to 0px on the left and right sides of the row.

Alternatively you can use a "full width section" to achieve the same thing.

Let me know if this works for you? we can also find another solution[image: design options, CSS box settings]